# Deformation of a piece of plastic inside a box

Tags: models, solid-mechanics

I wanted to know the final form of a solid, for instance a surface.

We have a rectangular elastic material of horizontal length equal to L, for example a piece of plastic (top Figure).

We put this material inside a box with horizontal length less that L, and we fixed it in its two vertical sides (bottom Figure). Because the horizontal length of the box is smaller, the shape of the plastic will be like a wave, and the number of waves will depend on the depth of the box.

Just as observarion, I can imagine only two posible solutions depending if the waves go to one side or the other, and for this reason I whink that this problem must be well posed, or at least it has sense.

In the middle Figure I show better the boundary conditions of the problem: two non-slip boundary conditions in the vertical sides, free boundary condition in the top and bottom sides, and a boundary condition back and forth.

Is this a known problem? What is the model problem? I suppose that it is a problem in solid mechanics, and is given by an PDE, but I do not understand what could be.

[image]

Comment: You refer to figures that aren't there.

Comment: Thanks @Gert , I added now.

Comment: This sounds very much like the Euler buckling model, but with the pillar being extended into a sheet. Presumably that is the easiest model, and that implies that for small bending the shape is sinusoidal. Except that it looks like you want bigger deformation, where the sine solution is no longer accurate.

Comment: Can you guide me a litte more, for example with a link or book to understand the situation? In the buckling model I always see bars, not surface. This is a prototype of my problem, I like to solve this problem inside a tetrahedral, for example, instead of a box. And I'm not sure if we can apply the Euler buckling model in more general cases.

Comment: Search Google Scholar for Euler buckling of a plate with rigid bilateral constraints ([example](https://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~herzl/2002/On%20the%20post-buckling%20behavior%20of%20bilaterally%20constrained%20plates.pdf)). There are dozens of papers addressing analytical and numerical techniques.

Comment: In addition, since you're essentially considering just a wide column (i.e., bending around only one axis is considered), I believe you should be able to simply apply column solutions, with the additional adjustment that Young's modulus $E$ should be replaced by the [plane strain Young's modulus $E^\prime=E/(1-\nu^2)$](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/297b/fd5257d0cf9b785e9157e26d3f3a26bdb0e0.pdf) because Poisson deformation is constrained in plates.

Comment: [Another reference](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1081286517741341). [Another](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c8e/8cf893c3f60c3e2a08a946c0f0931e400067.pdf). [Another](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/B-Royce/publication/225323364_Constrained_Euler_Buckling/links/58d034f692851c8841c2826c/Constrained-Euler-Buckling.pdf). [Another](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1084.1235&rep=rep1&type=pdf).